# How do I check if a requests.Session is authenticated without making an example request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, python-requests

Let's say I have a `requests.Session`, as follows:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.auth = ('username', 'password')
```

Given the code above, how do I verify whether the authentication is valid? Currently, with the Github API, I just make a sample request and see if the response is 401, in which case the authentication is invalid.

Is there a way to check this authentication *without* having to make a sample request?

Comment: If you could do that, you'd be able to brute-force peoples' accounts at insane speeds, not bounded by your Internet speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Only the server knows whether your authentication is valid, and the way to communicate with the server is by making a request.